# If I deposit A-tokens to contract, then contract owns A-tokens?

Tags: erc-20

If I deposit A-tokens(erc20) to smartcontract, then smartcontract owns A-tokens?
If so, is it possible another user send TX to the smartcontract above to interact with another smartcontract with A-tokens included?

should I do something like approve and transferfrom to make this case feasible?

Comment: The answer to your first question is "yes". The rest of your questions are a bit unclear. It might help if you wrote some code and shared that here.

Comment: I'm not sure about the rest either. In case it helps, yes, the contract that owns the tokens could have a function that users would interact with to instruct it do something with those tokens. That could be sending somewhere else, paying for something, sending to the user or something tlse. A contract can do anything a user can do _if_ there is code so it knows _how_.